# how to make my first Item from my form as default in my select field

Tags: django, forms, field

I'm trying to get my select item to have a default value and with it get rid of this ------ in my select item but I can't use a default in my model
because I'm overriding the field like this

```
def __init__(self,researcher, *args,**kwargs):
        super (ProjectForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs) # populates the post
        self.fields['ubc'].queryset = Ubc.objects.filter(researcher=researcher)
```

I need the default to be the first item in my filter. How it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the initial values in the view

```
initial_value = Model.objects.filter(filter_params)[0]
form = Form(initial={‘field_name’:initial_value})
context = {‘form’:form}
```